# ruby gem for parsing serialized PHP-array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm consuming a SOAP webservice with savon v2 and within the response a get a serialized PHP-array which i need to parse in.

is there a ruby or rails gem providing this feature?

the php array string looks like this:

```
"a:5:{s:4:\"link\";s:88:\"https://www.12345.de/kundenmeinung.php?kunde=a2ca9498f6f7695aa518d6d6ed9fec7b&shop=12345\";s:4:\"hash\";s:32:\"a2ca9498f6f7695aa518d6d6ed9fec7b\";s:11:\"known_since\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"done\";i:1;s:7:\"done_at\";i:1358413353;}"
```

regards

Carsten

Comment: That's a bad, bad web service if you ask me. Response should be in a common interoperable format (JSON is my favourite). Do you have control over that service?

Comment: i totally agree, it is a thirdparty webservice we do not have control off, so i need this bad work around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# gem search -r php|grep serial

php-serial (0.9.5)
php-serialization (0.5.3)
php-serialize (1.1.0)
php-serialize4ruby (0.0.0)
php-serialize_ryan (1.1.1)
php_serialize (1.2)
viva-php_serialize (1.1.3)
```

so there's at least 7 of them.

Comment: thx i tried php-serialize (1.1.0) and it will do ;)